# Loop in coroutine stops after going halfway

Tags: unity, game-loop, coroutines

I have a very weird problem with a particular loop in a coroutine:

```
    public IEnumerator DestroyCubesGameOver() {
    var startingCubeHolder = GameObject.FindWithTag("StartingCubeHolder");
    DestroyOutOfCameraCubes();

    Debug.Log(cubeGroup.transform.childCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < cubeGroup.transform.childCount; i++) {
        Debug.Log(i);
        Destroy(cubeGroup.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.001f);
    }

    Destroy(startingCubeHolder);
}
```

The loop starts doing its thing and it needs to do it 100 times for example. However it stops after going about halfway and after destroying about half of the objects. Even if I increase the delay for each repeat it still does the same exact thing - needs to repeat itself and destroy 100 objects, ends after destroying just 50. What is causing this?

Edit: If I make it just a `void` method it destroys all of the objects.

Edit 2: This loop was initially a `foreach` but I rewrote it to try the other way - same thing.

Comment: I just had a similar issue with a coroutine behaving weirdly. Try adding `continue;` after your `yield` statement.

Comment: @Leggy7 Didn't help. Still stops after going halfway. This is so odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each loop you destroy one object so your childcount goes down, at the half your i and childcount meet and the loop stops.